# Android - adjust individual application volume

Tags: java, android, youtube, spotify, android-music-player

Is there any library that allows me to create an application that can adjust volume of individual application?

More specifically, I am creating an "sound mixer" application where the user can play multiple sounds with their desired volume. So in my application say the user open Spotify / YouTube music via inexplicit intent. Is there any way, I can lower the volume of the playback of that given application only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change system volume by interacting with AudioManager. Just need to remember prefered volume level for each app and set to that level based on what app user opens.